# How to check what color depth my monitors are using in Ubuntu 14.10 (Unity)?

Tags: color-depth

Preferably command line. Is there any?

Answer (score 11):

From this [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1178315&p=7399476#post7399476):

```
xwininfo -root | grep Depth
```

Comment: Default depth is 24, right?

Comment: @RohithMadhavan apparently so. That's what I get.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan muru i am getting 24 also. but in windows it shows 32. whats wrong

Comment: I think ubuntu uses a default of 24.

Comment: 32 bits of colour depth actually mean 24 bits to encode colour and 8 bits to encode transparency/opacity. The difference between X.org and Windows comes down to a linguistic problem.

Comment: @muru `xwininfo -root | grep Depth` gives me `24` but `xwininfo | grep Depth` and then selecting another window with the mice give me `32`. Which is the color depth my monitor is using `24` or `32` ?